# System of three equations with $e$

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve the following system of equations:

$0.001213=A+B.e^{30C}$

$0.002817=A+B.e^{40C}$

$0.00793=A+B.e^{50C}$

I tried elimination method but I got no answer. What I did was multiplying the first equation with -1 and summing it.

Could you please help me on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: The second or third equation has a type (repetition of DHS).

Comment: @Piquito Sorry there was a typo. I updated the post.

Comment: Have you considered [asking your question there ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Not sure what you mean?

Comment: After eliminating $A$, you have two equations of the form $a=Be^{cC}$ where $a,c$ are constants.  If $B$ were also constant, how would you find $C$?

Comment: Hint: Isolate exp(30C) from eq 1, exp(40C) from eq 2, and exp(50C) from eq 3. Then divide pairs of eq to eliminate B.

Comment: [Not sure what you mean?]---> Sorry, my fault, I thought I was on Mathoverflow. OK now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention the pattern of $e^{30C},e^{40C},e^{50C}$ and notice 40-30=50-40, which gives us a hint  where to start.

$0.001213=A+B.e^{30C}$(I)

$0.002817=A+B.e^{40C}$ (II)

$0.00793=A+B.e^{50C}$  (III)

(II)-(I) $0.001604=B.(e^{40C}-e^{30C})$ =$B.e^{30C}(e^{10C}-1)$ (IV)

(III)-(II) $0.005133=B.(e^{50C}-e^{40C})$=$B.e^{40C}(e^{10C}-1)$ (V)

(V)/(IV) $\frac{5133}{1604}$=$\frac{e^{40C}}{e^{30C}}$=$e^{10C}$, $ln \frac{5133}{1604}$=10C $\to$
C= $\frac{ln \frac{5133}{1604}}{10}$

With C known, substract (I) and (II) to find B. With B,C known, use (I) to find A.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT $$\begin{cases}a=A+B.e^{30C}\\b=A+B.e^{40C}\\c=A+B.e^{50C}\end{cases}\Rightarrow\frac{c-b}{b-a}=\frac{e^{50C}-e^{40C}}{e^{40C}-e^{30C}}=\frac{e^{20C}-e^{10C}}{e^{10C}-1}$$
Put $X=e^{10C}$ so you have a quadratic equation
$$(b-a)X^2-(c-a)X+(b-c)=0$$ from which $C=\dfrac{\ln(X)}{10}$, etc.